# How to scroll resized jframe(GUI Java app)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jscrollpane

i'm tired of searching solution for my problem, which is, I have Java swing application, with Jframe,JtabbedPane,and 4 Jpanel's. Frame is set like

```
frmPartsWarehouse.setExtendedState(frmPartsWarehouse.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frmPartsWarehouse.setResizable(true);
frmPartsWarehouse.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frmPartsWarehouse.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
```

Now, is there a way to set scroll's when size of screen decrease less than components, I now that problem is with Jpanel's because layout is set to absolute(null) and components are always the same place, but is there a way to get scrolled window when the screen is smaller. As example, it is Ok when the screen is 1024x768 and bigger,but when it is 1024x600(laptop 10``), I don't see all components

Comment: *layout is set to absolute(null)* - that would be the problem. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers (not a null layout). Scrolling will only work properly when you use layout managers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for those who have the same problem
I have changed frame layout to gridLayout,than create JScrollPane and add tabbed pane to scroll, and scroll to frame content pane, the code is like this

```
frmPartsWarehouse.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1,0,0)); 

    JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1327,678));
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabPane);      
    scroll.setEnabled(true);
    frmPartsWarehouse.getContentPane().add(scroll);
```

The scroll will scrolling only to the preferredSize of tabbPane!
And yes, this is solution for this problem, but IT IS much better to have gridBagLayout in my case, because frame will not depend of screen size and components will enlarge according to screen size, but it's working for scrolling.